# WHEA BSODs, dump analysis/advice, please

Tags: windows-10, bsod

Googling around brought me here. In short, my PC has started to experience these nasty random BSODs, sometime during gaming, but also just shortly after a reboot or randomly. I've even underclocked the CPU, seems to have no effected. I am also 99% this started happening with some Windows Update, but it might be a coincidence. This used to be a very stable PC just a few weeks ago, but who knows, after what I have read, it might just be dying since it seems to be a CPU thing. I obviously hope I am wrong, but I lack the knowledge to analyze dumps other that what I did with Whocrashed. I hope somebody can take the time to look at these dumps I uploaded.

Thanks a lot!

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxlW53y8xiDFYUI0VG15dDhqRDg

Comment: what does your windbg analyze show?

Answer (score 0):

[Checking the dumps with Windbg](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-15-WinDbg-Bugchecks) shows that you have an issue with the L1 Cache (ICACHEL1_IRD_ERR) of your `AMD FX-8350`.

```
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

WHEA_UNCORRECTABLE_ERROR (124)
A fatal hardware error has occurred. Parameter 1 identifies the type of error
source that reported the error. Parameter 2 holds the address of the
WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure that describes the error conditon.
Arguments:
Arg1: 0000000000000000, Machine Check Exception
Arg2: ffffd78ca2ed4028, Address of the WHEA_ERROR_RECORD structure.
Arg3: 00000000b0800000, High order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.
Arg4: 0000000000060151, Low order 32-bits of the MCi_STATUS value.

Debugging Details:
------------------

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10.0.15063.413 (WinBuild.160101.0800)

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.

BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  FD

BIOS_DATE:  02/04/2013

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd.

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  990XA-UD3

0: kd> !errrec ffffd78ca2ed4028
===============================================================================
Common Platform Error Record @ ffffd78ca2ed4028
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Record Id     : 01d2e9d7cd3d4eef
Severity      : Fatal (1)
Length        : 928
Creator       : Microsoft
Notify Type   : Machine Check Exception
Timestamp     : 6/20/2017 17:40:56 (UTC)
Flags         : 0x00000000

===============================================================================
Section 0     : Processor Generic
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffd78ca2ed40a8
Section       @ ffffd78ca2ed4180
Offset        : 344
Length        : 192
Flags         : 0x00000001 Primary
Severity      : Fatal

Proc. Type    : x86/x64
Instr. Set    : x64
Error Type    : Cache error
Operation     : Instruction Execute
Flags         : 0x00
Level         : 1
CPU Version   : 0x0000000000600f20
Processor ID  : 0x0000000000000000

===============================================================================
Section 1     : x86/x64 Processor Specific
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffd78ca2ed40f0
Section       @ ffffd78ca2ed4240
Offset        : 536
Length        : 128
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Local APIC Id : 0x0000000000000000
CPU Id        : 20 0f 60 00 00 08 08 00 - 0b 32 98 3e ff fb 8b 17
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 - 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Proc. Info 0  @ ffffd78ca2ed4240

===============================================================================
Section 2     : x86/x64 MCA
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Descriptor    @ ffffd78ca2ed4138
Section       @ ffffd78ca2ed42c0
Offset        : 664
Length        : 264
Flags         : 0x00000000
Severity      : Fatal

Error         : ICACHEL1_IRD_ERR (Proc 0 Bank 1)
  Status      : 0xb080000000060151
```

You can try the Beta BIOS `FEh` from 2014, maybe it helps. Check temperature, maybe the CPU overheats. If nothing helps, the CPU is damaged.

Time to move to AMD Rizon CPU with new motherboard.

Comment: I know it's suggested to comment for thinking, yet I still want to take this time and thank you. Much appreciated.